# How to list the open files in vim and quickly traverse the list?

Tags: vim

Currently I sometimes run vim with a wildcard, e.g. like this:

```
vim *.cpp
```

This works well, as I can then use `:next` and `:prev` to look at each of the `.cpp` files in sequence.

Where it falls down a little bit is when there are *many* files matching the wildcard, and I want to skip past several dozen/hundred of them quickly.  E.g. typing `:next` 96 times in a row isn't much fun.

So my question is, is there some keystroke or command that will cause vim to list out all of the files that matched the wildcard-expansion, and allow me to "jump" directly to a file in the list, without having to laboriously `:next` my way down to it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To list all of the open files:

```
:ls
```

to go to a particular file, use `:[count]b`.  eg, to go to the file listed as number 6 from `:ls`, do :

```
:6b
```

Answer (score 2):

An obvious improvement would be to be more discriminating right from the start and only open files you are actually interested in. In some shells, you can do things like:

```
$ vim {foo,bar,baz}/*.cpp
```

which will only open `*.cpp` files from the `foo`, `bar`, and `baz` subdirectories.

Another, huge, improvement would be to only open a single file, say `main.cpp`, and move around your projects from symbols to symbols. See `:help ctags`, `:help cscope`, and `:help include-search` for the built-in solutions, and look up "LSP" for a more modern approach to the problem.

Typing `:next<CR>` 96 times is indeed not fun so the problem at hand is really a scalability problem. Let's see what we can do with what we get out of the box…

- `:help cmdline-completion` gives us `<C-d>` to list the suggestions non-interactively, `<Tab>`, `<S-Tab>`, `<Down>`, etc. to drill down the suggestions, the wildmenu to navigate the suggestions in the status line.
- `:help file-searching` gives us the wildcards `*` and `**`.
- `:help :filter` can be used to make a long `:ls` more manageable.

And that's about it. Of the methods above, `:filter <pattern> ls`, possibly with a mapping to save on typing (or prevent looking slow and indecisive in animated gifs), seems to be as far as we can go with the built-ins:

[image: filter]

If you are not against plugins, fuzzy finders like fzf.vim or CtrlP are also a possibility.

My advice: switch to symbol-based navigation.